# Out.println() in programming

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gmt

I have two lines that I want to print on my Main App Screen. I tried to set them equal to a variable to print on the main screen. What I put into the Java file was:

```
public class TimeZoneConverter {

            public void main(String args[]) {

             //Date will return local time in Java  
             Date localTime = new Date(); 

             //creating DateFormat for converting time from local timezone to GMT
             SimpleDateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");

             //getting GMT timezone, you can get any timezone e.g. UTC
             converter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

             String1 = System.out.println("local time : " + localTime);;
             String2 = System.out.println("time in GMT : " + converter.format(localTime));

            }
        }

}
```

It says the strings cannot be resolved to a variable. How would I try to get this onto my main screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to set them equal to a variable to print on the main screen.

This is how you extract them to variables.

```
String localTimeStr = "local time : " + localTime;
String gmtStr = "time in GMT : " + converter.format(localTime);
System.out.println(localTimeStr);
System.out.println(gmtStr);
```

[System.out.println()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) returns a void. You cannot assign that to anything.

[EDIT]

Since you're looking to print this on an Android screen use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) or find a text view and [set it's text](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Comment: How do I get them onto the main screen though?

Comment: You mean the android screen ?

Comment: Yep, would I have to put a textview on the main screen and then print them through there?

Comment: Yes you could do that. Edited my answer to reflect your updated question.

Comment: I tried to do this in my XML:
`<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />`

and this in my Java:

`TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
myTextView.setText("Local Time:" + localTime);`

And it's still not coming up, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell since the code has been posted in the comments section. You're better off creating a new question for this. It will receive fresh attention and the context will be better.

Comment: I'm taking this to a new page. For the variable part, I'm setting this as my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> It says the strings cannot be resolved to a variable.

That's because you didn't declare them!  Specifically, you are trying to assign to variables `String1` and `String2` which were not declared, and therefore are not recognized by the Java compiler.

But even if you did declare them, the code still wouldn't work.  The reason is that `println` is a `void` method; i.e. it doesn't return anything.  And the Java language won't let you assign "nothing" to a variable ... 'cos it doesn't make sense.

See @Reimus's answer for the right way to write those statements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all  `Syste.out.println()` does not return anything. It is a void. So you have to say like this:

```
 System.out.println("local time : " + localTime);
 System.out.println("time in GMT : " + converter.format(localTime
```